# ove between the different fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have five different kind of fragment for view pager. Each fragment has an imageview and if I clicked that image, the next fragment will replace the current one like a way I have planned and works on it. From my works, if I clicked the image on the first fragment, it will move to the second fragment perfectly. But if I click the image on the the second fragment it takes to me the fourth fragment instead of the third fragment. How can I fixed that one.

listener I have used in the activity:

```
@Override
    public void onMoveFragmentDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);
    }
```

Image on the fragment:

```
yesOptionImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MoveYesorNo_FragmentListener moveyesnoFragment = (MoveYesorNo_FragmentListener) getActivity();
            yesOptionImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.yesactive);
            noOptionImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
            GetAnswer.question=getArguments().getString(Ques1);
            GetAnswer.questionCode=getArguments().getString(QuesCode1);
            GetAnswer.questionType=getArguments().getString(QuesType1);
            GetAnswer.answer="Yes";
            moveyesnoFragment.onMoveYesorNoFragmentDialog();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yesOptionImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 int action = event.getAction()
switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          MoveYesorNo_FragmentListener moveyesnoFragment =      (MoveYesorNo_FragmentListener) getActivity();
            yesOptionImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.yesactive);
            noOptionImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
            GetAnswer.question=getArguments().getString(Ques1);
            GetAnswer.questionCode=getArguments().getString(QuesCode1);
            GetAnswer.questionType=getArguments().getString(QuesType1);
            GetAnswer.answer="Yes";
            moveyesnoFragment.onMoveYesorNoFragmentDialog();
        return true;

        }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If i clicked the image on the fragment, the transition occurs very quickly so is there is any possibility to slow down the transition between the fragments.